# Array y objetos en javascript

Tags: jsonarray

Necesito realizar lo siguiente
Imprimir en la página HTML, mediante document.write y/o la funciones que estime
conveniente, la lista de consultas médicas de Dental. Sin embargo, debe hacerlo
separando por un guión cada dato desplegado y cada fila de información debe estar
separada por un párrafo.
La información del json es

```
let objDos = {
Dental: [
  {
      HORA: "8:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
      PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
      RUT: "11123425-6",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "11:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
      PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
      RUT: "9878789-2",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  },
  {
      HORA: "11:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
      PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
      RUT: "7998789-5",
      PREVISION: "FONASA"
  },
  {
      HORA: "13:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
      PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
      RUT: "18887662-K",
      PREVISION: "FONASA"
  },
  {
      HORA: "13:30",
      ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
      PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
      RUT: "17665461-4",
      PREVISION: "FONASA"
  },
  {
      HORA: "14:00",
      ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
      PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
      RUT: "14441281-0",
      PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
  }
]
}
```

He probado con el siguiente código

```
const paci = Dental.map(function(paci) {
    return Dental.PACIENTE;
});
 
console.log(paciente);
```

Y repitiendo lo mismo para cada propiedad. Aunque esto solamente extraerá cada propiedad de los objetos por separado y yo necesito extraer las propiedades de cada objeto y concatenarlas con el símbolo "-"

Comment: De la forma como lo pides siento que nos estas dejando tarea jajaja, edita la pregunta agregando el codigo con el que trataste de resolver el problema para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Primero guardo el objeto a iterar en una variable.

   ```
    let array = objDos.Dental;
   ```
2. Luego itero dentro de cada item del array

   ```
       for(item of array){
   ```
3. Creo un array vacío donde almacenaré cada propiedad(value) del recorrido.

   ```
        let paragraph = []
   ```
4. Ahora vuelvo a iterar pero cada propiedad del item obtenido en el primer recorrido y su valor lo ingreso en el array vacío que se declaró.

   for(let value in item){
   paragraph.push(item[value]);
   }
5. Por ultimo cuando termino el segundo recorrido, realizo un join(" - ") para unir todo lo que esta almacenado en el array e imprimo en la vista.

   document.write(`<p>${paragraph.join(" - ")}</p>`);
6. Cierro el ciclo for.

   ```
          }
   ```

Completo:

```
let array = objDos.Dental;
for(item of array){
    let paragraph = []
    for(let value in item){
        paragraph.push(item[value]);
    }
    document.write(`<p>${paragraph.join(" - ")}</p>`);
}
```

Comment: Hola Everto. Gracias por tu respuesta